# How to process parallel HTTP request in go programming language?

Tags: go

I was playing with the go HTTP package. I wanted to process request in parallel as I do in java. But I couldn't.

I created a simple web server, put a sleep in the middle and realized that go process one request per time, so if I did a refresh on my browser, the process of the first request has to finish until the second request start processing, here is the code:

```
func main(){

    //Process the http commands
    fmt.Printf("Starting http Server ... ")
    http.Handle("/", http.HandlerFunc(sayHello))
    err := http.ListenAndServe("0.0.0.0:8080", nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("ListenAndServe Error",err)
    }
}

func sayHello(c http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    fmt.Printf("New Request\n")
    processRequest(c, req)
}

func processRequest(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request){
    time.Sleep(time.Second*3)
    w.Write([]byte("Go Say’s Hello(Via http)"))
    fmt.Println("End")
}
```

As I wanted to process both request in parallel I added the "go" command before "processRequest(c, req)" in "sayHello" function in order to process each request in a different gorutine. But... it doesn't work.... I don't know why. I know that both request are processed because I see the printed line at the console but the browser keep waiting for information..... and don't show my response.

So... my questions,

Does each request create a new http.ResponseWriter? or it's use the same?
Do you know how to indicate the web server to process each request with different threads?

Any help is welcomed....

Fersca

Answer (score 22):

All connections are automatically handled concurrently. Each TCP connection (not request) gets its own goroutine.

In a world with http pipelining and browsers that reuse connections, this may not always work out well. Most likely your browser is reusing a connection which stalls it until the current request being processed by the goroutine finishes.

Comment: Thank you. So many time wasted today just because of browser's too smart behavior :)

Answer (score 0):

To allow the run-time support to utilize more than one OS thread you might want to set that number via:

```
 runtime.GOMAXPROCS(n)
```

or set the GOMAXPROCS environment variable.

To get the number of available cores, use

```
 runtime.NumCPU()
```

So you often end up with

```
 runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())
```

Comment: This does not help. Go is concurrent by default, just not multithreaded (there's a big difference between the two). It will switch to a different goroutine on blocking calls like `time.Sleep()` and `.Write()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your browser is waiting because you did not sent a response back to it
Your browser made a request to sayHello and sayHello also made a request to processRequest,
from your code processRequest sent back a response to sayHello but sayHello did not send back a response to the browser.

you can use http.Get or http.Post to call processRequest